# Tracking the number of string elements using std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash-map

I'm looking for the most simple and efficient way to track the number of string elements in a container.

Previously, I used [`std::vector`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200490/better-container-for-tracking-number-of-string-elements) but I tried changing the container to `std::unordered_map` since I hear that it can be easier and more performant for my use.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Table
{
public:
    void insert(const std::string &name)
    {
        auto it = data.find(name);
        if (it == data.end())
        {
            data[name] = 1;
            return;
        }
        data[name]++;
    }
    void remove(const std::string &name)
    {
        auto it = data.find(name);
        if (it == data.end())
            return;
        if (--data[name] == 0)
            data.erase(it);
    }
    /* get the number of occurrences */
    int count(const std::string &name)
    {
        auto it = data.find(name);
        if (it == data.end())
            return 0;
        return data[name];
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> data;
};

int main()
{
    Table table;
    table.insert("Apple");
    table.insert("Apple");
    table.insert("Orange");
    table.insert("Orange");
    table.remove("Orange");
    std::cout << "Number of Apples : " << table.count("Apple") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of Oranges : " << table.count("Orange") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of Lemons : " << table.count("Lemon") << std::endl;
}
```

**The Result :**

```
Number of Apples : 2
Number of Oranges : 1
Number of Lemons : 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Is there a way to improve the class `Table` so my program can be more efficient than now?

The program seems to work but I used `std::unordered_map` for the first time so I'm not really sure if my implementation is correctly done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void insert(const std::string &name)
{
    auto it = data.find(name);
    if (it == data.end())
    {
        data[name] = 1;
        return;
    }
    data[name]++;
}
```

If it is available, you should prefer taking `std::string_view` parameters over `std::string const&`. You see, every time you do:

```
table.insert("Orange");
table.remove("Orange");
```

a string has to be constructed for "Orange". Especially when all you're doing is removing or getting the count, that's very wasteful. `std::string_view` is very lightweight, and automatically converts from both C-strings and `std::string`. Even in the case of `insert()`, because your inserts are conditional, it's worthwhile.

Now your `insert()` can be simplified quite a bit because when you do `data[???]` with an `unordered_map`, and `???` is not in the map, it *automatically* gets inserted with a default value. For int, the default value is 0.

So all you need is:

```
void insert(std::string_view name)
{
    ++data[name];
}
```

`remove()` works, but it's not very efficient. The problem is that after you find the element and have the iterator... you throw that information away! Then you use `data[name]` which has to do another search.

Instead, use what you've got. When you have the iterator, use it.

```
void remove(std::string_view name)
{
    auto const it = data.find(name);
    if (it != data.end())
    {
        if (--it->second == 0)
            data.erase(it);
    }
}
```

`count()` has bit of a bug, and it's one the compiler would have informed you about if you'd made the function `const`.

The bug is that, as with `remove()`, after finding the element and getting an iterator to it, you throw that information away and use `operator[]`... but in this case, `operator[]` is non-`const`, meaning it might modify the map. That's not something you want happening if you're just getting a count.

Once again, the solution is to simply not throw the iterator away, but to use it:

```
int count(std::string_view name) const noexcept
{
    auto const it = data.find(name);
    if (it == data.end())
        return 0;
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to decrement the count in `remove`.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be simpler to merge 2 `if`s inside `remove()` so it can be like `if (it != data.end() && --it->second == 0) data.erase(it);`

Comment: the string will be created anyway in `++data[name];` when calling operator[], won't it?

Comment: Strange that none of my comments from last night are showing up. They were: 1) Thanks, hoffmale, fixed; and 2) Zack Lee, that's how I would write it, but I was trying to follow your convention of one test per `if`. And yes, RiaD, the string will be created every time, but it's `insert()`, so you shouldn't be using it in a hot loop context anyway.

Comment: @indi but what's the point of accepting string_view instead then? It'll be slower if somebody has a `std::string` and the same if it has something else (cstring/string_view etc). And the same applies to `count` which may be called often. PS: when you use  name without at-sign, the person is not get notified

Comment: @RiaD the `string_view` explanation was a general explanation (a follow up to the previous version of the code), not specific to `insert()`.